# Regex for string using GNU C regex library

Tags: c, regex, gnu

I am writing a regex to use with the GNU C regex library:

The string is of the form: (text in italics is a description of content)

> *(NOT a #)* start *(maybe whitespace)* : data

I have written the following code, but it won't match.

```
regcomp(&start_state, "^[^#][ \\t]*\\(start\\)[ \\t]*[:].*$", REG_EXTENDED);
```

What do I need to write?

examples:
to match:

> state   :  q0
>      state: q0
>          state:q0s

not to match:

> #state :q0
>   state q0
>     # state  :q0

Thanks!

Comment: can you please post some concrete examples?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The pattern in your question was consuming the first letter in `state` with `[^#]`, which left the match unable to proceed because it tries to match `tate` against the pattern `\(state\)`.

You passed the flag `REG_EXTENDED` which means you don't escape capturing parentheses but do escape literal parentheses.

With regular expressions, say what you *do* want to match:

```
^[ \\t]*(state)[ \\t]*:.*$
```

as in

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <regex.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  struct {
    const char *input;
    int expect;
  } tests[] = {
    /* should match */
    { "state : q0", 1 },
    { "state: q0",  1 },
    { "state:q0s",  1 },

    /* should not match */
    { "#state :q0",  0 },
    { "state q0",    0 },
    { "# state :q0", 0 },
  };
  int i;
  regex_t start_state;
  const char *pattern = "^[ \\t]*(state)[ \\t]*:.*$";

  if (regcomp(&start_state, pattern, REG_EXTENDED)) {
    fprintf(stderr, "%s: bad pattern: '%s'\n", argv[0], pattern);
    return 1;
  }

  for (i = 0; i < sizeof(tests)/sizeof(tests[0]); i++) {
    int status = regexec(&start_state, tests[i].input, 0, NULL, 0);

    printf("%s: %s (%s)\n", tests[i].input,
                            status == 0 ? "match" : "no match",
                            !status == !!tests[i].expect
                              ? "PASS" : "FAIL");
  }

  regfree(&start_state);

  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
state : q0: match (PASS)
state: q0: match (PASS)
state:q0s: match (PASS)
#state :q0: no match (PASS)
state q0: no match (PASS)
# state :q0: no match (PASS)
```

Comment: Very thorough! Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I figured it out:

```
regcomp(&start_state, "^[^#]*[ \\t]*start[ \\t]*:.*$", REG_EXTENDED);
```

above solves my problem! (turns out, I forgot to put a * after [^#])...

Thanks for your help anyway, Rubens! :)

Comment: How strict do you want to be about what's on the left side of the colon? That pattern also allows "foobarbazstart: xyz" to match, for example.

Answer (score 0):

This works with your sample data:

```
^[^#]\s*\w+\s*:(?<data>.*?)$
```

**EDIT**: I don't know, but you'll need to enable multiline support, as first `^` and last `$` have a different behavior with that setting.